# Real Analysis II: Chain Rule Application

Tags: real-analysis

I missed two weeks' worth of classes in my Real Analysis II course die to personal issues, and while going over past exam questions for midterm revision, I came across some problems that I had trouble even attempting to try, due to lack of background knowledge.

> Let $f(x,y)$ be a function of class $C^2$, and let $z=x+iy, z^*=x-iy$. Represent $\frac{\partial}{\partial z^*} \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ in terms of partial differentials with respect to $x,y$ using the chain rule.
>   (Regard $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f$ (or $z^*$) as $\frac{\partial }{\partial z}$ on $f(g(z,z^*))$ with $g$ being $g(z,z^*) = (x,y)$.)

Thanks in advance for any help given, may it be hints, guidance on which material to look at, a rough sketch of a solution, et cetera.

Comment: Please post the second question as a seperate one.

Comment: @martini Done! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question: Let's compute $g$. We have $z = x+iy$, $z^* = x-iy$, hence 
$$ z + z^* = 2x, \quad z - z^* = 2iy $$
or 
$$ x = \frac 12(z+z^*), \quad y = \frac 1{2i}(z-z^*)$$
giving 
$$ g(z,z^*) = \left(\frac 12(z+z^*), \frac 1{2i}(z-z^*)\right) $$
Taking derivatives, we have 
$$ \def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \p gz(z,z^*) = \left(\frac 12, \frac 1{2i}\right), \qquad \p g{z^*}(z,z^*) = \left(\frac 12, -\frac 1{2i}\right) $$
By the chain rule
$$ \p fz = \p fx \cdot \p {g_1}z + \p fy \cdot \p{g_2}z
         = \frac 12 \p fx + \frac 1{2i}\p fy = \frac 12\left(\p fx - i \p fy\right) $$
and
$$ \p f{z^*} = \p fx \cdot \p {g_1}{z^*} + \p fy \cdot \p{g_2}{z^*}
         = \frac 1{2} \p fx - \frac 1{2i} \p fy 
         = \frac 12\left(\p fx + i \p fy\right) $$

Comment: Despite StackExchange suggesting that I avoid comments like "thanks", thank you very much indeed! The fact that you detailed every step made it so helpful.